# List Local Users, group membership and Enabled status to single csv file using Powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to create a .csv file listing all local users, each user's group memberships and whether or not the user account is enabled using Powershell.

I have found [this](http://answer%20that%20I've%20been%20able%20to%20modify%20to%20iterate%20over%20a%20list%20of%20machines%20on%20the%20network,%20but%20I%20can't%20figure%20out%20how%20to%20get%20enabled%20status.%20%20I%20also%20found%20this%20answer,%20but) answer that I've been able to modify to iterate over a list of machines on the network and I've figured out how to output to a single csv file, but I need to include the machine name in my output file.  Thanks for any help/hints...

```
Function Check-Enabled ($Username) 
{
-not (Get-WmiObject Win32_UserAccount -filter "LocalAccount=True AND Name='$Username'").disabled
}

$Nodes= "Machine1", "Machine2", "Machine3"

ForEach ($Node in $Nodes)
{  
$adsiPath = ("WinNT://" + $Node)
$adsi = [ADSI]$adsiPath 

If (Test-Connection -BufferSize 32 -Count 1 -ComputerName $Node -Quiet)
    {
        $SingleMachine = $adsi.Children | where { $_.SchemaClassName -eq 'user' } | ForEach-Object {
            $groups = $_.Groups() | ForEach-Object {
                $_.GetType().InvokeMember('Name', 'GetProperty', $null, $_, $null)
            }
            $_ | Select-Object @{n='UserName';e={$_.Name}},
                               @{n='Groups';e={$groups -join ';'}},
                               @{n='Enabled';e={Check-Enabled $_.Name}}
        } 
        $AllMachines += $SingleMachine  
    }     
}

$AllMachines | Export-CSV -NoTypeInformation -Path ("C:\Users\"+$env:UserName+"\Desktop\AR-SingleFile.csv")
```

Comment: Insert  `@{n='Node';e=$Node},` to the `Select-Object`

Comment: Adding `@{n='Node';e=$Node}` to the `Select-Object` did not help.  Output file remains unchanged.

Comment: I think its because `$Node` isn't part of the pipeline feeding into the `Select-Object` statement.  I think what I'm looking for is a property of the `SchemaClassName 'user'` that will give the enabled status, but I think by the time data reaches the `Select-Object` statement, its dealing with a Group, not a User.  I think what need to happen, is the piping from one statement to the next needs to be broken up to make the properties of different object available to `$SingleMachine` variable.

Comment: It' inside the foreach, so $Node is valid. But forgot the curly braces around `e={$Node}`

Comment: That did it!  [This](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234) says I should be able to mark this post as answered, but there are no arrows next to the answers.  But please consider this post answered for anyone searching in the future,

Comment: You can mark a comment as useful, but only answers can be check marked and upvoted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert another calculated property to the Select-Object

```
        $_ | Select-Object @[n='Node';e={$Node}},
                           @{n='UserName';e={$_.Name}},
                           @{n='Groups';e={$groups -join ';'}},
                           @{n='Enabled';e={Check-Enabled $_.Name}}
```